# Plotting an histogram in log log scale with identical bar thickness

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot input data in an histogram in log-log scale (to quickly view if this could fit a power law), but I'm having trouble in outputting the way I want. I'm using Python and more specificaly the matplotlib/numpy libraries:

```
thebins = N.linspace(min_data.min(),min_data.max(),int(sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]))
thebins = N.log(thebins)
bar_min = plt.hist(min_data,bins=thebins,alpha=0.40,label=['Minimal Distance'],log=True)
```

min_data is my 1d data array, the two first lines are for creating the bins and then putting them in a log scale. The final line is for 'filling' the bins/histogram with log y scale.

The graphical output is:

[image]

It may seem fussy but I'm not satisifed with having bins of different thickness, it seems to me that the data is harder to read or can even be misread from that. Not all log-log histogram have same width bins and I'm convinced it can be done within Python; do you have an idea of to change my code to get there?

Thank you in advance ;)

Should have been a nobrainer: I only had to take the log of my data for the x axis, and then build the histogram passing the argument "log=True" for the y axis.

Comment: I am not clear your are doing your binning correctly.  I think you want to be using `logspace` to generate the bin edges.

Comment: Instead of editing the question to add the answer you found yourself, please post it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.